# Undefined Symbols when trying to compile RtAudio

Tags: macos, compilation, makefile, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to use RtAudio and RtMidi together. I have in the same folder RtAudio.cpp, RtAudio.h, RtHelper.h, RtMidi.cpp and RtMidi.h as well as 2 test programs, midiprobe.cpp and audioprobe.cpp.

Compiling midiprobe with the [default command](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling) works, but when I try to do the same for [audioprobe](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/compiling.html) to test RtAudio, I get the errors.

Here is what I use to compile:

```
g++ -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o audioprobe audioprobe.cpp RtAudio.cpp -framework CoreAudio -lpthread
```

And these are the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_CFRelease", referenced from:
  RtApiCore::getDeviceInfo(unsigned int)in cc89M9Ki.o
"_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
  RtApiCore::getDeviceInfo(unsigned int)in cc89M9Ki.o
"_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
  RtApiCore::getDeviceInfo(unsigned int)in cc89M9Ki.o
"_CFStringGetSystemEncoding", referenced from:
  RtApiCore::getDeviceInfo(unsigned int)in cc89M9Ki.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm quite new to this sort of stuff (mostly had frameworks ready-made till now) and haven't been able to figure this out yet. Since it's the default example, I'm really lost as to what to do next... 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try adding `-framework CoreFoundation`.

Comment: OK - great - I've converted my comment to an answer - please mark it as accepted for the benefit of future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing symbols are in the CoreFoundation framework - you need to add:

```
-framework CoreFoundation
```

to your command line.